# Date.getMillisOf NullPointerException

Tags: java, junit, powermock

I have this method to test

```
public static AccountingYear newInstance(Date startingDate, Date endingDate) {
    if ((startingDate == null) || (endingDate == null)) {
        throw new AccountingRuntimeException(
                "the range specify is not correct");
    }

    AccountingDaoFactory daoFactory = (AccountingDaoFactory) UnitOfWork
            .getCurrent().getDaoFactory();
    AccountingYear lastAccoutingYear = daoFactory.getAccountingYearDao()
            .getLastAccountingYear();
    Date startDate = lastAccoutingYear.startingDate;
    Date endDate = lastAccoutingYear.endingDate;
    if (lastAccoutingYear != null
            && isDateRangesOverlap(startDate, endDate, startingDate,
                    endingDate)) {
        throw new AccountingYearCollisionException();
    }
    if (endingDate.before(startingDate)) {
        throw new EndingDateIsBeforeStartingDateException();
    }
    AccountingYear newAccountingYear = new AccountingYear(startingDate,
            endingDate, true);
    if (isOldAccountingYear(startDate, endingDate)) {
        newAccountingYear.setSatus(AccountingYearState.OLD_AND_NOT_CLOSED);
    }
    newAccountingYear.save();
    return newAccountingYear;
}
```

This is the corresponding test

```
@Test
public void newAccountingYearTest() throws Exception {
    AccountingYear accountingYear = Mockito.mock(AccountingYear.class);
    Mockito.when(accountingYear.getAllPeriods()).thenCallRealMethod();
    objectToTest = AccountingYear.newInstance(startingDate, endingDate);
    Assert.assertNotNull(objectToTest);
    Assert.assertEquals(2, objectToTest.getAllPeriods().size());
    Assert.assertEquals(AccountingPeriodType.Opening, objectToTest
            .getAllPeriods().get(0).getType());
    Assert.assertEquals(AccountingPeriodType.Closing, objectToTest
            .getAllPeriods().get(1).getType());
}
```

When i run the test i have this exception: Java.lang.nullPointerexception, at Java.util.Date.getMillisOf,Date.before().
This is isOldAccountingYear code that give the exception

```
public static boolean isOldAccountingYear(Date startDate, Date endingDate2) {
    if (endingDate2.before(startDate)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Please can you help me solve the problem

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. It doesn't *look* like you should be able to get a `NullPointerException` there. It's not clear why you're using Mockito at all for `AccountingYear`, mind you - what are you trying to mock out? Also note that the body of your `isOldAccountingYear` method would be more clearly written as just `return endingDate2.before(startDate);` (And why do you have a 2 at the end of `endingDate2`?)

Comment: Can you post the full test code (i.e. `@Before` etc), we don't know what `startingDate`, `endingDate` are, and how is `daoFactory` / `lastAccoutingYear` "handled"

Comment: This is the whole code of tthe AccountingYear class

Comment: stupid me, by the headline I thought someone tries to get the millis of a NPE.

Answer (score 1):

Your description of the symptoms is unclear, but it seems you are saying that an NPE is thrown *within* the `before` call in `isOldAccountingYear`.  That implies that the `startDate` parameter is `null`.  (If `endingDate2` was `null`, then the NPE would be thrown by the `isOldAccountingYear` itself, not by the `before` method.)

I think you have a mistake in the code that calls `isOldAccountingYear`:

```
if (isOldAccountingYear(startDate, endingDate)) {
```

The prior code has carefully checked the `endingDate` parameter and it can't be `null`.  But `startDate` is a local variable whose value comes from a field of `lastAccoutingYear`.  It could be `null`.  I suspect that it is ... and that leads to the NPE.

I don't understand the real intent of this code (your variable naming is not helpful!) but I suspect that the above line should be:

```
if (isOldAccountingYear(startingDate, endingDate)) {
```